# System.IO extention

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, system.io.file, microsoft.ml

I am using Microsoft.ML in a project, and unfortunately on android it's giving me this error message when I try to load premade models:

```
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   : IOException: Permission denied
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   : Rethrow as UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/local/tmp/ml_dotnet/ydvub5x4.hap' is denied.
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory (System.String fullPath) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at Microsoft.ML.Repository.GetShortTempDir () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at Microsoft.ML.Repository..ctor (System.Boolean needDir, Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IExceptionContext ectx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IExceptionContext ectx, System.Boolean useFileSystem) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IExceptionContext ectx, System.Boolean useFileSystem) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
08-29 15:45:06.835 27752 23359 E Unity   :   at Micro
```

The problem is, I can't really modify anything inside Microsoft.ML, nor serialize its objects.
I also couldn't extend any of its classes since they are sealed.
I was thinking maybe there is an alternate System.IO that I can modify ? or maybe a way to extend the method that don't seem to work.
Please help

Comment: Is the path a setting and/or are you able to set the path's permissions?

Comment: On Android access to the filesystem is very limited.  You can't open or create a file at a random path.  If there's a configuration to set the path, use it.  If that path is hardcoded in your library, it's just not going to work on Android.

Comment: @Stefan no, it's Microsoft.ML that chooses to create a directory in/data/local/tmp/ml_dotnet/ I can't change that :/

Comment: @GabeSechan, for that I was actually thinking of maybe overloading the CreateDirectory method based on parameter value ? does this exist somehow ?

Comment: There's no way to do that.  That's a system library, its not like you're passing in an instance of System.IO.  And even if you could, you'd be potentially breaking a LOT of things.  Have you considered switching to something that's built for Android, like ML-Kit or Tensorflow?